# I need help to convert a C code to MPI

Tags: c, mpi

I now have an SGE cluster with the MPI runtime. As a beginner, I would like someone to help me translate the C code to MPI to run it later using the SGE queue system, but I do not get it.

I add the sequential code in C:

```
int initialize (double **A, int n)
{
   int i,j;
   for (j=0;j<n+1;j++){
     A[0][j]=1.0;
   }
  for (i=1;i<n+1;i++){
  A[i][0]=1.0;
  for (j=1;j<n+1;j++) A[i][j]=0.0;
   }
```

Comment: Why would you need MPI? this is just 20*50*50 times a handful of arithmetic operations. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: if you are looking for an MPI tutorial, I would suggest reading an MPI and possibly deleting this question. If you are looking for specific help on your problem, you could read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit you post. The conversion of your specific algorithm to MPI will really depend on the actual size of the data, data dependencies, execution platform, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on the relevant part of the code as I understand it (after removing the printf and probably erroneous `iters++`):

```
for (for_iters=1;for_iters<21;for_iters++) 
{ 
    diff = 0.0;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            tmp = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = 0.8*(A[i][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);
            diff += fabs(A[i][j] - tmp);
        }
    }
    if (diff/((double)N*(double)N) < Tolerance)
    {
        convergence=TRUE;
    }
}
```

Besides the issue that this is probably way too little processing to justify the extra work required to parallelize and distribute the algorithm, the fundamental problem is that there are data dependencies in both directions: the new value of A[i][j] depends on the old value of A[i][j] and:

- the new value of A[i-1][j] and A[i][j-1]; and
- the old value of A[i+1][j] and A[i][j+1]

As these dependencies go both directions, you end-up with very strong constraints in the order of the operations:

- the calculation of the new value of A[i][j+k] must happen after A[i][j] for all k>0; and
- the calculation of the new value of A[i+1][j] must happen after A[i][j+1]

With these constraints, you could conceivably have a parallel execution on N processes, where each process would calculate the new values for a given value of i, but you would need to synchronize the processor for line i with the processor for line i+1.

Conceptually it could be something like this:

```
double line_processor(int i, double **A, int n)
{
    // MPI: initialize communication with line processor for i-1
    // MPI: initialize communication with line processor for i+1
    double diff = 0.0;
    for (int j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        double tmp = A[i][j];
        // MPI: wait for A[i-1][j+1] to be calculated
        // MPI: get the new value of A[i-1][j]
        A[i][j] = 0.8*(A[i][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i-1][j] + A[i][j+1] + A[i+1][j]);
        // MPI: signal that A[i][j] has been calculated
        diff += fabs(A[i][j] - tmp);
    }
    // MPI: send the local value of diff for accumulation on the master process
    return diff;
}
```

Unfortunately, the MPI wait and signaling around the calculation of A[i][j] will take a lot more time than the calculation by itself, which will lead to an extremely inefficient use of compute resources and almost certainly a slower execution than the sequential implementation.

The detail of the MPI syntax to transfer the data and to synchronize the processes is probably better left in the relevant tutorials than copy/pasting here.

If you were having a very large large matrix it would become meaningful to revisit the problem and consider slicing the matrix.